# VB.Net "logger" asp:Table and asp:UpdatePanel dynamic asynchronous update

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, logging, updatepanel

I am writing a web page in ASP.Net. Presently, I have an `asp:Table` that I am using as a sort of "log" for processing output. The idea is that the user selects several files and clicks a button, and each file is "processed" with the log showing what is happening. Processing occurs asynchronously.

Here is the relevant processing segment:

```
    Protected Sub DoAsyncWork()

    Dim count = 0
    For Each row As GridViewRow In gvList.Rows
        count = count + 1
        If CType(row.FindControl("cbImport"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox).Checked Then

            push_to_log("")
            push_to_log("Updating Active Projects +" + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(1).Text).ToString.Substring(0, 30) + "...")

            Dim xp(3) As Object
            xp(0) = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(0).Text)
            xp(1) = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(1).Text)
            xp(2) = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(2).Text)
            xp(3) = 0
            'oDC.UpdateData("Import_P3e_Project ", xp)
            If (xp(3) <> 0) Then
                push_to_log("Success: " + xp(3).ToString + " have been updated")
            Else
                push_to_log("Failure: " + xp(3).ToString + " activities updated")
            End If

        End If


    Next
    push_to_log("")
    push_to_log("Import Complete!")

End Sub
```

This is how I am calling the process worker function:

```
Protected Sub button_Import(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnImport.Click
    Dim t As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf DoAsyncWork))
    t.Priority = Threading.ThreadPriority.Normal
    t.Start()
    push_to_log("Start Import")
End Sub
```

The way I am appending things to the log is by dynamically creating rows and cells, then adding them to my table. Here is the relevant subroutine:

```
Protected Sub push_to_log(ByVal str As String)

    Dim newRow As TableRow = New TableRow
    Dim newCell As TableCell = New TableCell

    logArrayList.Add(str)
    Me.ViewState.Add("arrayListInViewState", logArrayList)

    newCell.Text = str
    newCell.Style("Color") = "White"
    newCell.ID = "cell" + (logArrayList.Count - 1).ToString
    newRow.ID = "row" + (logArrayList.Count - 1).ToString

    newRow.Cells.Add(newCell)

    logTable.Rows.Add(newRow)

    HiddenButton_Click(HiddenButton, New EventArgs())
    'UpdateLogPanel.Update()
    'UpdateLogPanel.Focus()
End Sub
```

I've got the log persisting correctly by using the ViewState to store my arraylist of data and recreating the log on postbacks. The relevant markup for my log looks like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateLogPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
          <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="HiddenButton" />
        </Triggers>
          <ContentTemplate>
    <div ID="Div1" class="DefinitionPanel" style="text-align:left;height:200px;overflow:hidden;" runat="server">


       <span style="display:inline-block; width:100px;"></span>
       <div class="scrollingtable">
          <div>
            <div id="viewContainer">
              <asp:table id="logTable" runat="server" enableviewstate="false">

              </asp:table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <asp:Button ID="HiddenButton" runat="server" style="display:none;" />
          </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am trying to make my `asp:Table` update every time a message is posted to it. I thought that enabling partial postbacks and using an `UpdatePanel` would be the correct solution, but my log still does not output anything until the entire process has completed.

After I add a message to my `asp:Table`/log, I tried calling

```
UpdateLogPanel.Update()
```

which didn't seem to make a difference. Finally I tried adding the `asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger` and hidden button with the hope that it would fix things but it doesn't seem to. Here is what the `hiddenButton` event looks like:

```
Protected Sub HiddenButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles HiddenButton.Click
    UpdateLogPanel.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Any guidance on how to make my log re-render itself when I add a message to it would be highly regarded.

Comment: VB6.NET? Interesting. Time for an edit...

Answer (score 0):

I chose to implement using pooling instead of an asynchronous method.

I still use an asp:UpdatePanel. Instead of a table inside of the UpdatePanel, I am now using a gridview, and a timer. When the timer fires, I rebind the gridview, thereby showing any new contents

The key components to making this work:

Square things away with the parent update panel and master page:

```
Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    'set reference to master site page
    mstr = CType(Master, Site)

    'setup partial rendering so Log can update asynchronously
    scriptManager = CType(mstr.FindControl("ScriptManager1"), ScriptManager)
    scriptManager.EnablePartialRendering = True
    scriptManager.AsyncPostBackTimeout = 28800
    CType(mstr.FindControl("UpdatePanel1"), UpdatePanel).UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional
    CType(mstr.FindControl("UpdatePanel1"), UpdatePanel).ChildrenAsTriggers = False
End Sub
```

The mark-up for the UpdatePanel looks like

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateLogPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" 
            RenderMode="Inline" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" runat="server">
                  <ContentTemplate>
                       <%--The Gridview and other Hidden Fields--%>
                       <asp:Timer ID="myTimer" OnTick="timer_tick" runat="server" Interval="1000" Enabled="false"/>
                  </ContentTemplate>
                  <Triggers>
                      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="myTimer" EventName="Tick" />
                  </Triggers>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Triggering the logging mechanism is done simply by setting 
       myTimer.Enabled = True

The timer_tick event looks like

```
Public Sub timer_tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    generate_log() 

    //other logging logic (increment counters, "timeout" mechanism)

    UpdateLogPanel.Update()

End Sub
```